# SoapUI and absolute path

Tags: groovy, soapui

I managed to execute a bat file via `Groovy` in `SoapUI` with `Runtime.runtime.exec("cmd /c C:\temp\test.bat")` But I would like to have the bat file in a folder called scripts where my soapui-project file is.

Example:

```
Soapui-project file.xml

-- Scripts

--- test.bat
```

`Runtime.runtime.exec("cmd /c Scripts/test.bat")` doesn't work. I really need help here.

Comment: In order for that to work, the relative path has to exist within whatever the current working directory is.  How does your program know what the current working directory is?

Comment: Tried this
   ' def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
    def projectDir = groovyUtils.projectPath
    log.info(projectDir)'

    Runtime.runtime.exec("cmd /c projectDir Scripts/test.bat")

But that did not work

Comment: You do not want use absolute path becuase it fails on different machine, is that right?

Comment: Yes thats right

Comment: @user3624378, have you got chance to try the answer provided below?

Answer (score 1):

In a team, we share the project artifacts with different members and each may use different directory to copy them. So, in such situations absolute path in groovy scripts, like you mentioned, may not work if the directory gets changes.

To hand this, prefix of the path should be variable. And the rest of the path can fixed as the whole artifacts are still unchanged.

To handle that, use below which makes use of project directory as root and it gets that dynamically.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils
def path = new GroovyUtils(context).projectPath
log.info "Project directory : ${path}"
Runtime.runtime.exec("cmd /c ${path}/Scripts/test.bat")
```